# Eclipse not detecting Google Analytics V4 in imports

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-analytics

I just installed Google Analytics V4 API by using the SDK manager but when I try these imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
```

the words "com.google" are highlighted in red. This makes me believe I have to add some sort of file to my libs directory but I don't know what to do.

Comment: that some sort of file maybe a  required jar.

Comment: I don't think that's what the problem is

Comment: Analytics V4 is part of Google Play Services. Did you follow the [setup instructions](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)?

Comment: Have you added it to your build path?

Comment: "I don't think that's what the problem is". Fine, what message is shown when you hover over them? Are you *absolutely* *certain* that those classes are in a jar on the project's Java Build Path?

Comment: Add google play services library to your project. Problem would be solved. No need for jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Add google play services library to your project. First download it from sdk manager-> extras. Then, select project-> properties-> Android. Add the google play services project. No need to add jar files etc.